# How in procedure correctly to compare datetimes? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

In **PostgreSQL** database I create *procedure* which looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE tracker(CUSTOM_TIME VARCHAR) AS $FUNCTION$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE SURVEYS SET CONDITION = 3 WHERE CONDITION = 2 AND CUSTOM_TIME > END_PERIOD;
        UPDATE SURVEYS SET BLOCKED = TRUE WHERE CONDITION = 2 AND CUSTOM_TIME BETWEEN START_PERIOD AND END_PERIOD;
    END;
$FUNCTION$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I try to start this *procedure* it raise error.

```
CALL tracker('2019-03-29 16:37:00');
```

**Error**:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying > timestamp without time zone
No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
PL/pgSQL function tracker(character varying) line 3 at SQL statement
```

Where I make mistake?

Comment: "Where I make mistake?" -- Using `varchar` for a date/time. Use a date/time type like `timestamp` for the parameter `custom_time`.

Comment: I also tried it. I change it type of argument to `timestamp`. Result is the same when I call procedure. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function tracker(CUSTOM_TIME timestamp without time zone) RETURNS void
AS $FUNCTION$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE SURVEYS SET CONDITION = 3 WHERE CONDITION = 2 AND CUSTOM_TIME > END_PERIOD;
        UPDATE SURVEYS SET BLOCKED = TRUE WHERE CONDITION = 2 AND CUSTOM_TIME BETWEEN START_PERIOD AND END_PERIOD;
    END;
$FUNCTION$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you! I used this part from your code `CUSTOM_TIME timestamp without time zone`. I think it's better to use procedure instead of function in my case cause I return nothing.